# How to show tooltip next to the mouse cursor on SVG, despite Non-SVG elements on the website?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

**Aim:**
I have a website with some content and svg scheme in the middle of it. When one points to the elements of the scheme, tooltips should appear next to the mouse cursor.

**Problems:** Based on examples like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/mb5wz6ft/3/)    (which was shown by Julian Berger in [How to get the position of SVG element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25803158/how-to-get-the-position-of-svg-element)), I made working SVG. Unfortunately it is working only as long as the SVG scheme is not included into the website. Content other then SVG make evt.clientX and Y coordinates system to fail --> the tooltip starts to appear in some distance from the cursor (it seems that the more of other then SVG content I have, the further tooltip is moved away from cursor). The simple example is shown [here](http://jsfiddle.net/forrest1988/rkLk0hvq/), simply by adding couple of `<br/>` before the actual SVG begins.

**And my question:**
Do you have some ideas how to fix the position of the tooltip, so that it would appear always next to the moving cursor?

All the best,
Wojtek

Comment: Do the answers to this question help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4850821/svg-coordinates-with-transform-matrix

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is alter mousemove handler a little.  It should position the tooltip relative to the top left of the SVG, rather than the page.  You do that by subtracting the position of the SVG, which we get by surrounding the SVG with a `<div>` element and accessing its offsetLeft and offsetTop properties.

```
<div id="mysvg">
  <svg>...</svg>
</div>

function ShowTooltip(evt, mouseovertext) {
   svg = document.getElementById("mysvg");
   tooltip.setAttributeNS(null,"x",evt.clientX+11 - svg.offsetLeft);
   tooltip.setAttributeNS(null,"y",evt.clientY+27 - svg.offsetTop);
   ...
}
```

[Full demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/mb5wz6ft/5/)

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer Paul! This solution however does not work on my firefox (verion 34.0.5 for Mac OS X, and version 31.0 for windows), where the tooltip window freezes in the upper left corner of the SVG image. On the other hand it works perfectly on my Chrome 39.0.2171.95, Opera 26.0.1656.32 and Safari 7.1, but I have no clue so far how to fix it for firefox..

Comment: Sorry.  It looks like SVGs in FF don't have offsetLeft and offsetTop properties.  I've tweaked the answer. It should work everywhere now.